# Can't print an object outside a function

Tags: python, object

I'm making a simple program in order to compare the currentdate to another date, and I need to separate the "/" and remove trailing zeros; I made a function for that:

```
def correctdate(compare, Dayslist, Monthslist):
    for day in compare:
    
        if day == "/" or day == "\\":
            compare.remove(day)
            break
        else:          
            Dayslist.append(day)
                
    for removenum in Dayslist:
        #* Removing the numbers from the list
        compare.remove(removenum)
             
    for month in compare:
        Monthslist.append(month)
            
    #* Joining the numbers into a string
    correctdate.DaysLeft = "".join(Dayslist)
    correctdate.MonthsLeft = "".join(Monthslist)
    #* Stripping leading zeros
    correctdate.DaysLeft = correctdate.DaysLeft.lstrip("0")
    correctdate.MonthsLeft = correctdate.MonthsLeft.lstrip("0")

    return
```

The code works just fine but i want to save the `DaysLeft, Monthsleft` to print it/edit it ETC..
so i do this:

```
        correctdate(compare,Dayslist,Monthslist)
        print(correctdate.Daysleft)
```

and i get this:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'Daysleft'
```

Comment: I think you want to use a class instead of a function?

Comment: are you sure about that? Because i saw people do it that way but am receiving an error for some reason

Comment: Its a typo. You meant: `print(correctdate.DaysLeft)`

Comment: Please provide samples of input data and expected output(s). From the description of what you're hoping to achieve this seems overly complicated

Comment: Posting -1 to anwers wihout try it u wont be able to solve your problem

Comment: @quamrana
Thank you haha it was a typo for real, sorry for posting a whole question for such a silly mistake

Comment: @DarkKnight It turned out to be a typo, thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a typo in printing the object attribute

I wrote:

```
print(correctdate.Daysleft)
```

Its supposed to be:

```
print(correctdate.DaysLeft)
```

Sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

You ve to return it in your function, and outside it get it into variables:

```
def correctdate(compare, Dayslist, Monthslist):
for day in compare:

    if day == "/" or day == "\\":
        compare.remove(day)
        break
    else:          
        Dayslist.append(day)
            
for removenum in Dayslist:
    #* Removing the numbers from the list
    compare.remove(removenum)
         
for month in compare:
    Monthslist.append(month)
        
#* Joining the numbers into a string
correctdate.DaysLeft = "".join(Dayslist)
correctdate.MonthsLeft = "".join(Monthslist)
#* Stripping leading zeros
correctdate.DaysLeft = correctdate.DaysLeft.lstrip("0")
correctdate.MonthsLeft = correctdate.MonthsLeft.lstrip("0")

return  correctdate.DaysLeft,correctdate.MonthsLeft
```

This for return outside function, now you ve to call function correctly:

```
    DaysLeft,Monthsleft = correctdate(compare,Dayslist,Monthslist)
    print(DaysLeft,Monthsleft)
```

Anyway this code "correctdate.MonthsLeft" looks like you want use class and not only functions, so you should use like that https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp

Comment: I think that's another way to solve it, Turns out my code works just fine I just made a typo while printing. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

```
def correctdate(compare, Dayslist, Monthslist):
```

You declare a function with name `correctdate` that accepts 3 parameters.

```
correctdate.DaysLeft = "".join(Dayslist)
correctdate.MonthsLeft = "".join(Monthslist)
```

Then you try to assign a value to a function, which is not possible because `correctdate` is not a variable, not an object.  You just declared it as a function.

What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: *What are you trying to achieve?*. If you are not sure, keep asking for the clarification until you are sure

Comment: Its perfectly fine to add attributes to a function.

Comment: https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-access-a-variable-outside-of-a-function-in-python